# Color Console - Performance?

Tags: c#, console

i have a little question.

Im write my project at the moment but i think a "grey" console is boring.

Now is my question -> Can i use colors without performance loose?

For example with a public.

Best whishes

Comment: I was just kidding. You can use colors without any worries about performance.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the project it built, the "gray" color you are referring to is just like any other color you might choose. So when it comes to performance - it doesn't matter if you leave the default gray or use custom colors.

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to use some colors in my project for connection incomming or error whatever.. Thank you ! Have a nice day.